# How to check if arrays String element contains number

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Let's say I have an array:

```
var myArray = ["bla_01", "bla_02", "tra", "bla", "tra_01", "tra_14]
```

I want to sort them and get only strings, that contain numbers in it. So my `func` would have to return only "bla_01", "bla_02", "tra_01", "tra_14" values.

I have a code like this now, but this will get only the first values and if there is item_01, item_02, bla_02 this will drop only item_01, item_02 and ignore bla_02. And later to sort and return only same name values with the highest number.

```
    func unequeValues() {
    var number = 1
    for item in tricks {
        if item.contains("\(number)") {
              print(item)
            number += 1
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Where is your function?  Have you tried it for yourself?

Comment: Hey El Tomato. I have tried in various ways but don't know how to sort it and find not all value like : "bla" but the part of the value "01" , "02"... :     func unequeValues() {

        for item in myArray {
            if item.contains("01") {
                  print(item)
            }
        }
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter the array with regular expression (skip items without digits) and sort it numerically

```
let myArray = ["bla_01", "bla_02", "tra", "bla", "tra_01", "tra_14"]
let filteredArray = myArray.filter{$0.range(of: "[0-9]+", options: .regularExpression) != nil }
                           .sorted{$0.localizedStandardCompare($1) == .orderedAscending}
```

or more efficient if the last *good* character is always a number

```
let myArray = ["bla_01", "bla_02", "tra", "bla", "tra_01", "tra_14"]
let filteredArray = myArray.filter{$0.last?.isNumber == true }
                           .sorted{$0.localizedStandardCompare($1) == .orderedAscending}
```

The `rangeOfCharacter(from` solution can be considerably improved by adding the `backwards` option

```
let filteredArray = myArray.filter{$0.rangeOfCharacter(from: .decimalDigits, options: .backwards) != nil }
                           .sorted{$0.localizedStandardCompare($1) == .orderedAscending}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple Swift 4 version using rangeOfCharacter method from String class:

```
let myArray = ["bla_01", "bla_02", "tra", "bla", "tra_01", "tra_14"]

let filteredArray = myArray.filter{$0.rangeOfCharacter(from: .decimalDigits) != nil }
                               .sorted{$0.localizedStandardCompare($1) == .orderedAscending}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var myArray = ["bla_01", "bla_02", "tra", "bla", "tra_01", "tra_14"]

let newArray = myArray.filter { (substring) -> Bool in
    let numbersRange = substring.rangeOfCharacter(from: .decimalDigits)
    let hasNumbers = (numbersRange != nil)
    return hasNumbers
}
print(newArray)
```

Comment: And if I want to return only the highest values of the array, how to do that? As I used for item in myArray { item.suffix(2) }  I could convert that last 2 numbers into a Int and then compare because the type is different.